# Find all integer solutions of $y^2 = x^5 - 15x^4 + 10x^2 + 4x + 3$, or prove that none exist

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Question: Find all integer solutions of $y^2 = x^5 - 15x^4 + 10x^2 + 4x + 3$, or prove that none exist

Can anyone please solve this question for me? I have no idea how to start, so any comments are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Reduce mod 5.

Answer (score 5):

If we reduce modulo $5$ (as suggested in comments) we get
$$y^2\equiv x^5+4x+3\equiv x^5-x+3$$
By Fermat's little theorem, $x^5-x\equiv0\bmod5$. Thus $y^2\equiv3\bmod5$, which is impossible; $3$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $5$. Hence the original equation has no integral solutions.